# Apache redirect rule to block based on QUERY_STRING

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, rhel

I am trying to write rewrite rules to block URLs with following pattern below

```
 "GET /mysecure/Docs?cb=20414624755 HTTP/1.1" 200 881107 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
```

I am trying to block all requests with `QUERY_STRING` cb=20414624755 .

For this I have written the following rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^cb=20414624755$" [nocase]
RewriteRule ^\/mysecure\/Docs$ - [forbidden,last]
```

But the requests are not getting blocked. Not much knowledge on redirect rules , suggestions and solutions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where have you placed the rule and what does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: Nothing in error log and the access log shows 200 response code for the hists

Comment: Where have you placed the rule? Most likely it is not getting applied. Try placing a definite syntax error in the rule. Do you _then_ get an error if your log file? If not...

Comment: The rules are placed inside virtual hosts settings for this site . Putting a definite syntax error shows syntax error

Comment: Sounds fine and strange that things don't work as expected. Hm, maybe we see a unicode issue here? Characters looking identical but are not? Have a try reducing the patterns to see when they start matching.

Comment: Also a good start to debug stuff like this is to enable rewrite logging. See the documentation for details and how to. That feature allows you to look into your rewriting engine and see exactly what is going on, on a step by step base.